# Change event name

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

There is an observer in core module which is being called on `sales_order_place_after` event. I want it to call it for `sales_order_save_after` event. How do I override the `config.xml` file to change the event call name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do it so I cannot judge if it makes sense but as a heads up: this will have lots of side effects that you probably are not aware of, so be cautious!

Now for the technical answer: you cannot override the XML *file* but you can override individiual settings in a custom module because all config.xml files are merged into one structure.

For configuration files there is no way to *remove* previous nodes (the `sales_place_order_after` observer), but it's possible to change the type of an observer:

So let's say the original observer is

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <salesrule>
                <class>salesrule/observer</class>
                <method>sales_order_afterPlace</method>
            </salesrule>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

Then you can set the type of the `salesrule` observer to `disabled` in your own config:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <salesrule>
                <type>disabled</type>
            </salesrule>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

and then define a *new* observer for `sales_order_save_after`:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <salesrule>
                <type>disabled</type>
            </salesrule>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>

    <sales_order_save_after>
        <observers>
            <salesrule>
                <class>salesrule/observer</class>
                <method>sales_order_afterPlace</method>
            </salesrule>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
```

Note that module loading order is important for overrides, so your module must be loaded after the original module. Since it is a core module, this is already the case. Core modules are always loaded before community/local modules.

If it were not a core module, you would have to define a dependency in your `app/etc/modules` module activation file. But it's good practice to always make dependencies explicit:

```
<depends>
    <Mage_SalesRule />
</depends>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had to add depends tag for it to work.

Comment: Weird, if yours is a local module, the core module should always be loaded first. I extended the answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one more module:

Global Configuration file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Namespace_Newmodule>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <active>true</active>
        <depends>
            <Namespace_Oldmodule />
        </depends>
    </Name_Newmodule>
</modules>
```

After doing this your new module `config.xml` file will call first. If both observer is calling this way then you need to comment the event `sales_order_place_after` code from old module.